# don't wait till his fever gets so high

Tags: adverbs

a. She told me that if her son's fever got to 101 or higher she'd consult a doctor. I told her not to wait till his fever got so high.

b. She told me that if her son's fever got to 101 or higher she'd consult a doctor. I told her not to wait till his fever got ever so high.

Are both of the above grammatically correct?

I don't know if we need the 'ever' in (b).

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

*Ever so* is an informal expression for *very* - "His temperature
was ever so high!". It is inappropriate here, because we already know what temperature is being referred to.

Maybe you are thinking of *ever* in the sense *at any time.* "If his fever/temperature *ever* got to 101 she would send for the doctor."

Answer (score 2):

I would say that both (a) and (b) are grammatically correct, but they mean slightly different things.

In (a), we are disagreeing with the specific choice of 101 degrees Fahrenheit as the threshold for consulting a doctor. We think the threshold should be set lower than 101.

In (b), we are being less specific. We are advising that the doctor should be called before the boy's temperature gets "very high", without actually specifying a particular temperature as the point at which the doctor should be called.

In real life, I would always say (a), and never (b), because it just doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 1):

In sentence (a), you're advising her not to wait until her son's fever reaches such a high level. In sentence (b), adding "ever" puts extra emphasis on the high temperature, making the advice sound more urgent.

The use of "ever" in sentence (b) is less common and might sound a bit old-fashioned or formal to some people. In everyday conversation, most people would probably choose to use sentence (a).